# Laravel how can i display all image with slider from my public folder?

Tags: laravel

hello i want to show all image from public folder with slider.That's show all image code

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/' . $image->getFilename()) }}"
```

controller

```
$images = \File::allFiles(public_path('images'));
return view('welcome')->with('images',$images);
```

i want to show that all image with slide can anyone show me sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [owl carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html), in your `welcome.blade.php`

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
 @foreach($images as $image)
  <div class="item"><img src="{{ asset('images/' . $image->getFilename()) }}" /></div>
 @endforeach 
</div>
```

Comment: it have any way doesn't use theme.