# how can i display all image one by one from public folder

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

When I run this code it displays all the images from my public folder but I want to display them one by one.

```
 <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
         @foreach ($images as $image)
          <img src="{{ asset('images/' . $image->getFilename()) }}">
        @endforeach
</div>
</div>
   <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

controller

```
$images = \File::allFiles(public_path('images'));

return view('welcome')->with('images',$images);
```

Comment: You have asked similar question many times : https://stackoverflow.com/q/47976192/2815635

Answer (score 1):

```
    @foreach ($images as $image)
     <div class="item">
      <img src="{{ asset('images/' . $image->getFilename()) }}">
     </div>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the class="item" inside the foreach, keeping a class="item active".

Also you're missing the carousel-indicators so that the arrows can show the next and previous image.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp